# How to open a process and record stdin and stdout properly in Go?

Tags: go, io, subprocess, pipe, pipeline

I've been trying to write a program that record what is passed to a subprocess and the console returns in live (in the future, to record SSH sessions, for now on Python shell for testing)

I can record without issue stdout and stderr (it shows and record it correctly) but I can't find a way to do the same on stdin ?
Basically that my stdin will both map to the subprocess stdin and write to the log file.

There is my current code :

```golang
func SSH(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
    logFile := fmt.Sprintf("%v@%s.log", args[0], time.Now().Format(SSHLogDateFormat))
    usr, _ := user.Current()
    home := usr.HomeDir
    logDir := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s/logs", home, config.ConfigDir)

    if _, err := os.Stat(logDir); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        err = os.Mkdir(logDir, os.FileMode(int(0700)))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to create %s: %s", logDir, err)
        }
    }

    fullLogFile := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", logDir, logFile)

    log.Infof("Started recording to %s", fullLogFile)

    bash, err := exec.LookPath("bash")
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Could not locate bash: %v", err)
    }

    f, err := os.Create(fullLogFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to open device logs: %s", err)
    }

    command := exec.Command(bash, "-c", "python")

    out := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f)

    command.Stderr = out
    command.Stdout = out


    if err := command.Start(); nil != err {
        log.Fatalf("Error starting program: %s, %s", command.Path, err.Error())
    }
    err = command.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error waiting program: %s, %s", command.Path, err.Error())
    }


    f.Close()
    log.Infof("Finished recording to %s", fullLogFile)
}
```

Tried this too without success :

```golang
    out := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f)
    in := io.TeeReader(os.Stdin, out)

    command.Stderr = out
    command.Stdout = out
    command.Stdin = in
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader. Same principle as the MultiWriters, but as an io.Reader so assignable to Stdin.

Comment: It's not very clear how to us it ? I tried the following thing : (Added to the post)
But looks like it's the wrong way ?

Comment: "TeeReader returns a Reader that writes to w what it reads from r." I'm not sure what I could add that makes it clearer. I'm assuming what you want is `command.Stdin = io.TeeReader(os.Stdin, f)`. But since you haven't told us what you mean by "without success" we can only guess.

Comment: What happen is that it looks like it override the other writer as I'm only seeing what type (and only that is getting logged), the stdout is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write to the process's `stdin`. Get a write pipe to that:

```
procIn, err := command.StdinPipe()
if nil!=err {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Then create a multiWriter to write to both log and process:

```
inWriter := io.MultiWriter(procIn, f)
```

Finally, copy Stdin into the MultiWriter:

```
go func() {
  io.Copy(inWriter, os.Stdin)
  procIn.Close()
}()
```

We do the copy in a goroutine, so as not to hang everything up: we haven't started the command yet, so there's nothing receiving the written bytes. It needs to occur in parallel to the command running.

Here's a very simple example:

```
package main

import (
    `os`
    `os/exec`
    `io`
)

// pipeto copies stdin to logOut and to the command,
// and copies the commands stdout and stderr to logOut and
// to our stderr.
func pipeto(logOut os.Writer, cmd string, args ...string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command(cmd, args...)

    out := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, logOut)
    cmd.Stderr, cmd.Stdout = out, out

    procIn, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if nil!=err {
        return err
    }

    go func() {
        io.Copy( io.MultiWriter(procIn, logOut) , os.Stdin )
        procIn.Close()
    }()

    return cmd.Run()
}

func main() {
    logOut, err := os.Create(`logout.log`)
    if nil!=err {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer logOut.Close()
    if err := pipeto(logOut, `sed`, `s/tea/coffee/g`); nil!=err {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

You can test it, where I've named my go file `pipetest.go`:

```
echo this is a test of tea | go run pipetest.go
```

The you will see both the input and the output reflected in `logout.log`:

```
this is a test of tea
this is a test of coffee
```

Comment: No luck so far, I don't get any output anymore when trying this, looks like it's messing up with the other writer ?

Comment: I suggest removing your writers, and just using the ones I demonstrate in the example. If I've understood your question correctly, the example does what you want...

Answer (score 0):

At the end I found the solution by using the PTY library (That would have been needed anyway to handle special signals and tabs on subprocesses):  https://github.com/creack/pty

I took the `Shell` example and just replaced the `io.Copy` with my `MultiWriter`